# Creating tic/toc vector in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I built a GUI using the GUIDE feature in Matlab. I have many push buttons. I start by clicking one push button to start `tic`. Then when I click any of the other push buttons, I want to build a vector of `toc` time stamps. How do I do this?

Comment: newTime(currentCounterValue1+1) = toc;
assignin('base','output_to_workspace',newTime) --> only get the most recent newTime and 0's for the other times I push the button.

Comment: @sajawa: Set a breakpoint before the `assignin`. The code creates a new variable, then overwrites the previous content in the base workspace.

Comment: I think to get it to update each time the button is pushed, I need handles.newTime(size(handles.counter)) = toc; How do I initialize newTime as a variable? I keep getting the error undefined variable 'newTime'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most robust solution is to store and manipulate the vector in the GUI's handles structure. First, in your "create function", initialize the start and stop vectors:

```
function yourGui_CreateFcn ( hObject , eventdata , handles )
  % Initialize the start and stop vectors.
  handles.timeStart = [];
  handles.timeStop = [];

  % Update the GUI handles structure.
  guidata ( hObject , handles );
end
```

Then, in your first button, start the timer and store it to your handles vector.

```
function button1_Callback ( hObject , eventdata , handles )
  % Start the timer, updating the value in the handles structure.
  handles.timeStart = tic;

  % Update the GUI data so that timer is available to other functions.
  guidata ( hObject , handles );
end
```

Next, in each of your other button callbacks, retrieve the starting time from the handles structure and determine the elapsed time:

```
function button2_Callback ( hObject , eventdata , handles )
  % Retrieve the start time.
  timeStart = handles.timeStart;

  % Determine the elapsed time.
  timeElapsed = toc ( timeStart );

  % Store the new value in the handles structure.
  handles.timeStop(end+1,1) = timeElapsed;

  % Update the guidata.
  guidata ( hObject , handles );
end
```

Finally, you can output the values from the GUI using the "output function".

```
function yourGui_OutputFcn ( hObject , eventdata , handles )
  % Specify the output variables.
  varargout { 1 } = handles . timeStart;
  varargout { 2 } = handles . timeStop;
end
```

You would then execute your gui using the following statement in the command line:

```
>> [timeStart,timeStop] = yourGui ( );
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot.